# Maintain pair element reference type

Tags: c++, tuples, std-pair

Is there any way to forward a pair (or tuple)'s element while maintaining it's reference type (e.g., continue to be an rvalue)?

The below example demonstrates what I have tried: forwarding and moving the elements of a pair (first and second), moving the pair and using its elements, and moving both the pair and the elements. I would expect all to work, but none of them do.

```
template<class T, class U>
auto pair_forward(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(p.first), std::forward<U>(p.second));
}

template<class T, class U>
auto pair_move_elem(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::move(p.first), std::move(p.second));
}

template<class T, class U>
auto move_pair(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::move(p).first, std::move(p).second);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::pair<int, int&&> p(x, std::move(x));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(p.second)>::value); // works

    auto t1 = pair_forward(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t1.second)>::value); // fails

    auto t2 = pair_move_elem(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t2.second)>::value); // fails

    auto t3 = move_pair(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t3.second)>::value); // fails
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deduction rules for make_pair are confusing to me, so I suggest just calling the constructor directly with the types you want.

```
#include <utility>

template<class T, class U>
auto pair_forward(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::pair<T, U>(std::forward<T>(p.first), std::forward<U>(p.second));
}

template<class T, class U>
auto pair_move_elem(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::pair<T&&, U&&>(std::move(p.first), std::move(p.second));
}

template<class T, class U>
auto move_pair(std::pair<T, U>&& p)
{
    return std::pair<T, U>(std::move(p));
    // or just: return std::pair(std::move(p));
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::pair<int, int&&> p(x, std::move(x));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(p.second)>::value); // works

    auto t1 = pair_forward(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t1.second)>::value); // works

    auto t2 = pair_move_elem(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t2.second)>::value); // works

    auto t3 = move_pair(std::move(p));
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t3.second)>::value); // works
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/EfGe_x

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why it is that `make_pair` is unable to do this? Or `forward_as_tuple` for that matter?

Comment: Sorry, I just remember it's frustrating sometimes and it's easier to just avoid.